# User matching algorithm based on similar interests in a database

Tags: sql, cluster-analysis, graph-theory

Suppose I have tables defined as:

`user` with columns `user_id` `name` representing users

`interest` with columns `interest_id` `title` `weight` representing possible interests for users

`like` with columns `like_id` `user_id` `interest_id` representing a user's like of a particular interest

**Objective:** Given a particular user I want to get paged results of other users in descending order of most similarly liked interests. The solution needs to scale for 100k users and 100 interests.

The `weight` column indicates how much the interest should influence the result i.e an interest with weight of 3 should be 3x as influential as an interest with weight of 1.

The current database is in MySQL with a PHP API but we are happy to build something outside this stack for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL is rather slow.  You probably have reasons for choosing MySQL, but if performance is your primary concern, you probably should look into a database engine with better performance.  I would suggest SQLite.

The clustering code:

```
std::vector<double> cSharedLikesDB::cluster(int owner)
{
    // SQLite uses 1-based indexing
    owner++;

    // track time
    raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("DBcluster");

    // determing number of users, to size the output

    int userCount;
    while (sqlite3_step(countUsers) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        userCount = sqlite3_column_int(countUsers, 0);
    }
    sqlite3_reset(countUsers);

    std::vector<double> sharedScore(userCount + 1, 0);

    // find interests of owners

    std::string ownerInterests;
    int rc = sqlite3_bind_int(userInterests, 1, owner);
    while ((rc = sqlite3_step(userInterests)) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        if (!ownerInterests.empty())
            ownerInterests += ",";
        ownerInterests += std::string((char *)sqlite3_column_text(userInterests, 0));
    }
    sqlite3_reset(userInterests);

    // find users with matching interests
    
    std::string query = "SELECT userid,likeid "
                        "FROM like "
                        "WHERE userid != " +
                        std::to_string(owner) +
                        " AND likeid IN ( " + ownerInterests + " );";
    sqlite3_stmt *match;
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(), -1, &match, 0);
    while ((rc = sqlite3_step(match)) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        // found a match
        // std::cout << owner
        //           << " and " << sqlite3_column_text(match, 0)
        //           << " like " << sqlite3_column_text(match, 1) << "\n";

        // find weight of shared interest
        int other = sqlite3_column_int(match, 0);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_int(weight, 1, sqlite3_column_int(match, 1));
        rc = sqlite3_step(weight);
        sharedScore[other] += sqlite3_column_double(weight, 0);
        sqlite3_reset(weight);
    }
    sqlite3_reset(match);

    return sharedScore;
}
```

The complete application code is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/sharedLikes

Performance results:

| User count | Time secs |
| --- | --- |
| 1K | 0.001 |
| 10K | 0.01 |
| 100K | 0.1 |

If your database engine cannot deliver this performance, try using the database engine for persistent storage, and load the required data into memory, so that the calculations can be done using a high performance compiled language.  I would suggest C++.

Something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include "cRunWatch.h"

std::vector<std::string> userName;
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, double>> interest; // name, weight
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> like;                // user, interest

void populateFromdatabase()
{
    // ... this is a stub
}

void populateFromTest1()
{
    userName = {"Alice", "Bob", "Carol", "David "};
    interest = {
        {"football", 1},
        {"tennis", 2},
        {"golf", 3}};
    like = {
        {0, 0}, // Alice likes football
        {0, 1},
        {1, 1},
        {1, 2},
        {2, 2},
        {2, 0},
        {3, 2},
        {3, 0}};
}

void populateRandom( int userCount )
{
    for (int k = 0; k < userCount; k++)
        userName.push_back("user" + std::to_string(k));
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
        interest.push_back(std::make_pair(
            "interest " + std::to_string(k), k));
    for (int k = 0; k < userCount; k++)
        for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
            like.push_back(std::make_pair(
                k, rand() % 100));
}

    void cluster(int userID)
    {
        raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("cluster");

        std::vector<double> sharedScore( userName.size(), 0);

        // loop over user's interests
        for (auto &pui : like)
        {
            if (pui.first != userID)
                continue;

            // loop over other users
            for (int other = 0; other < userName.size(); other++)
            {
                if (other == userID)
                    continue;

                double other_score = 0;

                // loop over other user's interests
                for (auto &poui : like)
                {
                    if (poui.first != other)
                        continue;
                    if (poui.second != pui.second)
                        continue;

                    // found a shared interest
                    // std::cout << userName[pui.first] << " and " << userName[poui.first]
                    //           << " share " << interest[pui.second].first << " score " << interest[pui.second].second << "\n";

                    sharedScore[other] += interest[poui.second].second;
                }
            }
        }

        // sort into ascending order
        std::multimap<double,std::string> scoreMap;
        for (int k = 0; k < userName.size(); k++ )
        {
            if( sharedScore[k] > 0)
                scoreMap.insert(std::make_pair(sharedScore[k],userName[k]));
        }

        //display the cluster 
        std::cout << "\n"
                  << userName[userID] << "'s cluster\n";
        for (auto it : scoreMap )
        {
            std::cout << it.second << "\t" << it.first << "\n";
        }
    }
    main()
    {
        raven::set::cRunWatch::Start();

         populateFromTest1();
        //populateRandom(100000);

        cluster(0);
        cluster(1);
        cluster(2);
        cluster(3);

        raven::set::cRunWatch::Report();
        return 0;
    }
```

Which outputs

```
Alice's cluster
Carol   1
David   1
Bob     2

Bob's cluster
Alice   2
Carol   3
David   3

Carol's cluster
Alice   1
Bob     3
David   4

David 's cluster
Alice   1
Bob     3
Carol   4
```

The complete project is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/sharedLikes

The repo has code to do timing tests with various numbers of users.

| User count | Time secs |
| --- | --- |
| 1K | 0.003 |
| 10K | 0.3 |
| 100K | 30 |

These times exclude reading input data and displaying the results.